# Display specific content onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display some content, when clicking on a specific block.
I use 5 text-boxes, with underlaying text.

When clicking on one text-box, it should display specific content (text-block), that is based on that text-box. By default all text-blocks should be hidden by default, and only be displayed when clicking on the specific text-box.

How can I achieve that?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uknqqdga/1/

I use this code for that:

```
<div class="kernwaarden-circles">
   <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 text1">
      <p class="main-text text1">Text 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 text1">
      <p class="main-text text2">Text 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 text1">
      <p class="main-text text3">Text 3</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 text1">
      <p class="main-text text4">Text 4</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 text1">
      <p class="main-text text5">Text 5</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-1">
   </div>
</div>


<div class="text1-content" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="text2-content" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="text3-content" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="text4-content" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="text5-content" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `data` atrribute to indicate the content class.

```
<p class="main-text text1" data-content="text1-content">Text 1</p>
```

give all content a extra generic class `content`.

```
<div class="content text1-content" style="display: none;">
```

then, hide all `content` and show the relevant content from `data`:-

```
$('.main-text').click(function(){
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).data('content')).show();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uknqqdga/2/)

**EDIT**

> Thanks! Is it also possible to hide the content when clicking outside
>   the div? So that all content will hidden? And how can I animate the
>   display of the content?
>   And is it possible to add a active class to the  when it is active?

to animate there are a loads of different things you can do, `slideDown`/`slideUp`, `fadeIn`/`fadeOut`, etc.

clicking outside, you will need a `click` event on the parent `div` and `content`. this will also remove the *active* class.

```
$('.kernwaarden-circles, .content').click(function(){
    $('.content').slideUp();
    $('.col-sm-2.text1').removeClass('active');
});
```

then in the tab click you will need to `stopPropagation` so the click on the tab doesn't reach the hide click above.

```
$('.main-text').click(function(event){
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.col-sm-2.text1').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $('.' + $(this).data('content')).slideDown();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

here you remove the *active* from all, and add to the parent of the currently clicked tab.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uknqqdga/5/)

**EDIT 2**

> Great! Works perfect! Only last point, can it also be animated, when a
>   content div is displayed and clicking on another data-content.
>   Currently the div is animated to slide down. But can it also animated
>   to first slide up, to close the old content div and the slide down to
>   open the new content div?

```
$('.main-text').click(function(event){
    var active = $('.col-sm-2.text1.active');
    if(active.length){
        var that = this;
        $('.' + active.find('.main-text').data('content')).slideUp(500, function(){
            $('.' + $(that).data('content')).slideDown(500);
        });
    } else{
        $('.' + $(this).data('content')).slideDown();   
    }
    $('.col-sm-2.text1').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uknqqdga/6/)

**EDIT 3**

> Amazing!! Last question, the active div is also clickable and the the content div is slide up and down. Is it possible to disable the active class to be clickable?

you just need to check if the parent already has the *active* class.

```
$('.main-text').click(function(event){   
    event.stopPropagation();

    if($(this).parent().hasClass('active'))
        return;

    var active = $('.col-sm-2.text1.active');
    if(active.length){
        var that = this;
        $('.' + active.find('.main-text').data('content')).slideUp(500, function(){
            $('.' + $(that).data('content')).slideDown(500);
        });
    } else{
        $('.' + $(this).data('content')).slideDown();   
    }
    $('.col-sm-2.text1').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uknqqdga/7/)

**EDIT 4**

> I want the active div to be clickable, but that it will close.

```
if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
    $('.col-sm-2.text1').removeClass('active');
    $('.content').slideUp();
    return;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uknqqdga/9/)

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to hide the content when clicking outside the div? So that all content will hidden? And how can I animate the display of the content?

Comment: And is it possible to add a active class to the <div class="col-sm-2 text1"> when it is active?

Comment: Great! Works perfect! Only last point, can it also be animated, when a content div is displayed and clicking on another data-content. Currently the div is animated to slide down. But can it also animated to first slide up, to close the old content div and the slide down to open the new content div?

Comment: Amazing!! Last question, the active div is also clickable and the the content div is slide up and down. Is it possible when clicking on the active div, that it will close this active div?

Comment: I placed the last question to early and I edit it. I want the active div to be clickable, but that it will close.

Comment: remove `.content` from `$('.kernwaarden-circles, .content').click(function(){`. that closes the content.

Comment: Tried that, but that does not work. It does not slide up and close the content div

Answer (score 0):

Shortest thing I could think of is using the class name:

https://jsfiddle.net/uknqqdga/8/

```
$(function() {
    $(".main-text").click(function(e) {
        var contType=$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
        // Hide others here, etc..
        $("."+contType+"-content").show();
    });
});
```

It's a bit of a hack and using data-content as in other answer is much cleaner. But this requires no modification of HTML (sometimes you can't modify it).